Calculate the expected value of $S(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$
Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$, be observations of i.i.d. random variables with probability function $$\mathbb{P}(X_i=x_i)=p(1-p)^{x_i-1}$$ where $x_i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p\in(0,1)$.
I am asked to calculate the expected value of the estimator $S(x):=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$, as well as finding a sufficient statistic for $p$.

To compute the expected value of this estimator one must do the following $$\mathbb{E}(S(x))=\mathbb{E}\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\Big)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(X_i)=n\mathbb{E}(X_1)$$ where on the last equality we have used that the random variables are identicaly distributed. So now we need to compute the expected value of $X_1$, which is easy to see that $$\mathbb{E}(X_1)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}ip(1-p)^{i-1}=p\frac{1}{p^2}=\frac{1}{p}$$ since $X_1\sim\text{Geom}(p)$. So if I am correct, the expected value for our estimator is $$\mathbb{E}(S(x))=\frac{n}{p}$$ is that right? Also, when calculating the expected value for my estimator I have used a notational abuse by saying $\mathbb{E}(S(x))=\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)$ instead of using $x_i$. Does that effect in any aspect? Is it wrong if I do this? I understand that $X_i$ represents the theoretical random variable, whereas $x_i$ represents a given value for the sample but still, ignoring notational errors is it wrong?

Assuming that my result was correct, and I was asked to find an unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{p}$, defining my estimator to be $T(x)=\frac{1}{n}S(x)$ then I would have my result right? $$\mathbb{E}(T(x))=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}(S(x))=\frac{1}{n}\frac{n}{p}=\frac{1}{p}$$
Finally, in order to find a sufficient statistic for $p$ we must calculate the following $$\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_n=x_n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_1=x_n)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_i)$$ where on the first and second equalities, we have used the fact that the random variables are equally distributed and independent respectively. Now, $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(X_1=x_i)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p(1-p)^{x_i-1}=\frac{p^{n}}{(1-p)^{n}}(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$$ but how do I find my sufficient statistic from this deduction? What does my statistic need to be sufficient?

you should write $\mathbb E[S(X)]$ with $X = (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$

For sufficiency, I suggest to use the Factorization lemma of exponential families.

You are correct that $\mathbb E[S]=\frac np$ though some of your notation is slightly confusing.  $S(\mathbf X)$ is not an estimator of $p$ (or at least not a sensible one), but $S(\mathbf x)$ is a statistic.

Your $\frac{p^{n}}{(1-p)^{n}}(1-p)^{\sum x_i}$ might suggest that something like $\sum x_i$ or some function of it like $\sum (x_i-1)$ or $\frac1n\sum x_i$ or $\frac{n}{\sum x_i}$ could be a  sufficient statistic
